# Is something wrong with this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, conditional-operator

I'm trying to update a site that was coded horribly, and I think there is an error in this multiple IF statement. I've been Googling for a while and can't find any example of multiple IFs in a MySQL UPDATE query.

The idea is, we want to update a certain column of the row based on a different column of the row.

Here's the query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `pet_colors` AS c
SET c.inshop = 
IF(c.rarity='1', '25',
IF(c.rarity='2', '10',
IF(c.rarity='3', '3', '1')))
WHERE c.species='{$p->species}' AND c.buyable='1' LIMIT ".rand(1,3));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error or the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Looks like this one only updates some random rows (`.rand`). Is this what you want?

Comment: What exactly is your question first of all?  Second, why do this all in 1 query if it is too complicated, just run a query for each of the 3 cases.

Comment: @NickLarsen scores a point there. It would be clearer if done in 3 or 4 queries.

Comment: Yes, I do want it random. The unexpected behavior is that those with rarity of 3 are not being updated ever, it seems. As for doing multiple queries, that won't work because of the LIMIT random (that is random on species, not on color AND species.)

Comment: Is that a php/perl or some other script?
In that case, the tics around pet_shop try to execute it as a shell command.
What is exactly the error you're getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't think it's an error but rather a set of nested IFs. It would be easier to understand with a case statement in my opinion.

e.g.

```
Case c.rarity
When '1' then '25'
When '2' then '10'
When '3' then '3'
Else '1'
End
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what question are you answering?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a CASE statement instead of the imbricated IFs? It would be "as good" (or as bad, question of perspective), but easier to read.

```
[•••] SET c.inshop = CASE c.rarity WHEN '1' THEN '25' WHEN '2' THEN '10' WHEN '3' THEN '3' ELSE '1' END [•••]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what question are you answering?